# Building a 4 corners-colors CSS3 gradient

Tags: css, web

Is it possible to produce the following gradient in CSS :

[image]

Comment: Your best bet is probably splitting into a few gradients and using pseudo-elements.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

in your case

[image]

**Method 1:**

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ejEzy/2/)

```
div{
overflow: hidden;
background: #f06;
background: linear-gradient(45deg, #fff722, #ff26f9);
min-height: 100%;
width: 256px;
height: 256px;
position: relative;
z-index: 1;
box-shadow: inset -20px 0 38px -18px #ff26f9,inset -3px -13px 65px -18px yellow;
}

div:before,div:after{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
div:before{
    background: red;
    box-shadow: 0 0 140px 64px red;
    z-index:2;
    top: -96%;
left: -72%;
    opacity: 0.8;
}
div:after {
background: white;
z-index: 3;
bottom: -96%;
right: -72%;
box-shadow: 0 0 140px 64px white;
opacity: 1;
border-radius: 100%;
}
```

**Method 2:**

[image]

```
div{
overflow: hidden;
background: #f06;
background: linear-gradient(45deg, #fff722, #ff26f9);
min-height: 100%;
width:256px;
height:256px;  
position:relative;
    z-index:1;
}

div:before,div:after{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
div:before{
    background: red;
    box-shadow: 0 0 140px 64px red;
    z-index:2;
    top: -96%;
left: -72%;
    opacity: 0.8;
}
div:after {
background: white;
z-index: 3;
bottom: -96%;
right: -72%;
box-shadow: 0 0 140px 64px white;
opacity: 1;
border-radius: 100%;
}
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ejEzy/1/)

**Method 3:** multiple background:

[image]

```
div{
background: #f06;
background: linear-gradient(45deg, #fff722, #ff26f9),linear-gradient(142deg, transparent, white),linear-gradient(108deg, red, transparent);
min-height: 100%;
width:256px;
height:256px;  
position:relative;
    z-index:1;
}
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vjcLD/1/)

**Method 4:** pseudo element

```
div{
background: #f06;
background: linear-gradient(45deg, #fff722, #ff26f9);
min-height: 100%;
width:256px;
height:256px;  
position:relative;
    z-index:1;
}

div:before,div:after{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    opacity: 0.8;
}
div:before{
    background: linear-gradient(108deg, red, transparent);
    z-index:2;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
div:after{
    background: linear-gradient(142deg, transparent, white);
    z-index:3;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
}
```

the markup:

```
<div></div>
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vjcLD/)

**Method 5:**

```
div{
overflow: hidden;
background: #f06;
background: linear-gradient(45deg, #fff722, #ff26f9);
min-height: 100%;
width:256px;
height:256px;  
position:relative;
    z-index:1;
}

div:before,div:after{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
div:before{
    background: linear-gradient(108deg, red, transparent);
    z-index:2;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    opacity: 0.8;
}
div:after {
background: white;
z-index: 3;
bottom: -96%;
right: -72%;
box-shadow: 0 0 110px 54px white;
opacity: 1;
border-radius: 100%;
}
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ejEzy/)

Update: many thanks to **[Ana-Maria Tudor](http://about.me/thebabydino)**   <3

```
body{
position:fixed;
top:0;
right:0;
bottom:0;
left:0;
}

body:before {
  content: '';
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  border-radius: 0%;
  background:
    radial-gradient(circle at 50% 0, 
         rgba(255,0,0,.5), rgba(255,0,0,0) 70.71%), 
    radial-gradient(circle at 6.7% 75%, 
         rgba(0,0,255,.5), rgba(0,0,255,0) 70.71%), 
    radial-gradient(circle at 93.3% 75%, 
         rgba(0,255,0,.5), rgba(0,255,0,0) 70.71%);
}
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://dabblet.com/gist/9467973)

Comment: Thank You very much for the detailed and spanning answer ! I`ll keep it open in case someone has something to add but you definitely gave me a solution. We currently creating CKO, a visual intelligence kid that will get you to rediscover/access your images in an intelligent way. If you have some time to consult please let me know, your agility and passion are really cool.

Comment: Really an amazing answer and in-depth examples. +1

Comment: I'm struggling with graphic software and yet you've done with CSS - great!

Answer (score 15):

### SIMPLE

Just use this `background` style for your `div` element:

```css
.myDiv {
  width: 256px;
  height: 256px;
  background: linear-gradient(to top left, white, rgba(255, 153, 150, 0), red), linear-gradient(to top right, yellow, rgba(255, 153, 150, 0), magenta) rgba(255, 153, 150, 1);
}
```

```html
<div class="myDiv"></div>
```

Where `rgba(255, 153, 150, _ )` is the color in the `div` center and we use it at bottom with a=1 and in gradients with a=0 for Safari compatibility (for other browsers in gradients we can change `rgba(255, 153, 150, 0)` to `transparetn 50%`) .

Working, easy to edit example **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/4dthzjof/4/)**. Idea source [**here**](https://css-houdini.rocks/corners-gradient/).

### MEDIUM

We need to add and style div `:after` pseudo element:

```css
.myDiv {
  width: 256px;
  height: 256px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, red, yellow);
}

.myDiv::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, magenta, white);
  -webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(to left, white, transparent);
}
```

```html
<div class="myDiv"></div>
```

Working, easy to edit example **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/1sdea4y6/1/)**. Idea from [**TheDarkln answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48782928/860099) (i made pure css version).

### COMPLEX

```css
.myDivC{
    overflow: hidden;
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, yellow, magenta);
    width:256px; height:256px;  
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
}

.myDivC:before,.myDivC:after{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
.myDivC:before{
    background: red;
    box-shadow: 0 0 140px 64px red;
    z-index:2;
    top: -96%;
    left: -72%;
    opacity: 0.8;
}
.myDivC:after {
    background: white;
    z-index: 3;
    bottom: -96%;
    right: -72%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 100px 64px white;
    opacity: 1;
    border-radius: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="myDivC"></div>
```

Box shadow and more pseud-elements - easy to edit code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nby7c3f0/3/). Idea from [**Gildas.Tambo answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18453171/860099) (I choose second solution - first has artefacts "black shadow" on bottom left corner, other solutions not works on Edge).

### TEST

It was [tested](https://jsfiddle.net/frv6qjbt/2/) versions:

- simple - on **Safari** (low but acceptable quality), **Chrome**, **Firefox** and **Edge**
- medium - on **Safari**, **Chrome**, **Firefox** (not works on **Edge**).
- complex - **Chrome**, **Edge**. In **Safari** and **Firefox** has "red-box' artefact on left top corner - which can be reduce by change in `.myDivC:before{ ... top: -96% ...}` to `top: -100%` but we loose red intensity a little  ([here](http://jsfiddle.net/nby7c3f0/4/)),

Below is comparison for 3 versions on chrome:

[image]

In simple solution we se more "linearity", the medium has the best quality. The complex quality is lower: asymetry and artefact red rectangle in left upper corner - this can be more clear to see when we change yellow to black in all solutions - [**here**](https://jsfiddle.net/frv6qjbt/4/):

[image]

### Conclusion

- **Simple** version - works everywhere however gives little bit lower (linear) quality than other solutions (especially on Safari)
- **Medium** version - gives the best quality but not work on Edge
- **Complex** version - works everywhere witch quality better than simple but worse than medium version, but code is very unhandy and needs more time to prepare, test and maintain[.](https://jsfiddle.net/8ao4u9n3/1/)

### UPDATE

Recently I develop solution which has both: high quality and is portable - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53681663/860099).

Answer (score 7):

### HIGH QUALITY and PORTABLE

In [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53602030/860099) I compare three solutions - but I found fourth solution which produce HIGH quality image and **works on Chrome, Safari, Firefox and Edge** - here it is:

```css
.myDiv {
    width: 256px; height: 256px;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,%3Csvg preserveAspectRatio='none' viewBox='0 0 1 1' version='1.1' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3ClinearGradient id='g'%3E%3Cstop offset='0' stop-color='%23fff' stop-opacity='0'%3E%3C/stop%3E%3Cstop offset='1' stop-color='%23fff' stop-opacity='1'%3E%3C/stop%3E%3C/linearGradient%3E%3Cmask id='m'%3E%3Crect x='0' y='0' width='1' height='1' fill='url(%23g)'%3E%3C/rect%3E%3C/mask%3E%3ClinearGradient id='a' gradientTransform='rotate(90)'%3E%3Cstop offset='0' stop-color='magenta'%3E%3C/stop%3E%3Cstop offset='1' stop-color='white'%3E%3C/stop%3E%3C/linearGradient%3E%3ClinearGradient id='b' gradientTransform='rotate(90)'%3E%3Cstop offset='0' stop-color='yellow'%3E%3C/stop%3E%3Cstop offset='1' stop-color='red'%3E%3C/stop%3E%3C/linearGradient%3E%3C/defs%3E%3Crect x='0' y='0' width='1' height='1' fill='url(%23a)' mask='url(%23m)'%3E%3C/rect%3E%3Crect x='0' y='0' width='1' height='1' fill='url(%23b)' mask='url(%23m)' transform='translate(1,1) rotate(180)'%3E%3C/rect%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}
```

```html
<div class="myDiv"></div>
```

In this solution we inject SVG dataurl image into CSS style. We can freely change `width` and `height` in `myDiv` (to allow it we use in svg `preserveAspectRatio='none'`, and additionaly `background-size: 100% 100%;` for [firefox support](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26049949/860099)). Colors used inside svg are `magenta, white, yellow, red` and can be changed to any css-format color. To have compatibility with MS Edge, in solution SVG we change following characters: `"` to `'`, `<` to `%3C` , `>` to `%3E`  and `#` to `%23` (info from [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52337855/860099)).

[image]

editable example [**here**](https://jsfiddle.net/wb6erhjL/4/). Svg background generator is below (or [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Lamik/7r5bqks0/)).

```js
function generateCSS() {
  let str = svgData.innerHTML;

  let r = str
    .replace('width="256" height="256" ', "")
    .replace('colorTopLeft', colorTopLeft.value)
    .replace('colorTopRight', colorTopRight.value)
    .replace('colorBottomLeft', colorBottomLeft.value)
    .replace('colorBottomRight', colorBottomRight.value)
    .replace(/> +/g, ">")
    .replace(/ +</g, "<")
    .replace(/>/g, "%3E")
    .replace(/</g, "%3C")
    .replace(/>/g, "%3E")
    .replace(/#/g, "%23")
    .replace(/"/g, "'")
    .replace(/ +/g, " ")
    .replace(/^ +/g, "")
    .split("\n")
    .join("");


  svgToText.value = `background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,${r}");`
  lengthCss.innerText = `length: ${r.length}`

  preview.style = svgToText.value + '; display: block;'
}
```

```css
.topForm {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.previewBox {
  display: none;
  margin-left: 20px;
  width: 256px;
  height: 256px;
}
```

```html
<div class="topForm">
  <div>
    <div><input id="colorTopLeft" value="red"> top left</div>
    <div><input id="colorTopRight" value="magenta"> top right</div>
    <div><input id="colorBottomLeft" value="yellow"> bottom left</div>
    <div><input id="colorBottomRight" value="white"> bottom right</div>
    <div><button onclick="generateCSS()" style="margin: 20px">Generate CSS</button></div>
  </div>
  <div id="preview" class="previewBox"></div>
</div>



<textarea cols=70 rows=18 id="svgToText" style="top:20px;" placeholder="output CSS background-image"></textarea>

<div id="lengthCss"></div>

<template id="svgData">
  <svg width="256" height="256" preserveAspectRatio='none' viewBox='0 0 1 1' version='1.1' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'>
      <defs>
          <linearGradient id='g' >
              <stop offset='0' stop-color='#fff' stop-opacity='0'/>
              <stop offset='1' stop-color='#fff' stop-opacity='1'/>
          </linearGradient>
          <mask id='m'>
              <rect x='0' y='0' width='1' height='1' fill='url(#g)'/>
          </mask>
          <linearGradient id='a' gradientTransform='rotate(90)'>
              <stop offset='0' stop-color='colorTopRight'/>
              <stop offset='1' stop-color='colorBottomRight'/>
          </linearGradient>
          <linearGradient id='b' gradientTransform='rotate(90)'>
              <stop offset='0' stop-color='colorBottomLeft'/>
              <stop offset='1' stop-color='colorTopLeft'/>
          </linearGradient>
      </defs>

      <rect x='0' y='0' width='1' height='1' fill='url(#a)' mask='url(#m)'/>
      <rect x='0' y='0' width='1' height='1' fill='url(#b)' mask='url(#m)' transform='translate(1,1) rotate(180)'/> 
  </svg>
</template>
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5):

By employing **[mask-image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask-image)** along with linear gradients, we can accomplish a seamless, 4-colored-corners gradient that only requires an `::after` pseudo element.

**HTML**

```
<div id="quad">
</div>
```

**SASS**

```
@mixin QuadVertexColors($v0, $v1, $v2, $v3) {

  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, $v0, $v2);

  &::after {

    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, $v1, $v3);
    -webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(to left, white, transparent);
  }
}

body {

  background-color: #111111;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;

  #quad {

    $size: 100vh;

    width: $size;
    height: $size;

    @include QuadVertexColors(red, magenta, yellow, white);
  }
}
```

**[CodePen Demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GQvYXe)**