# IE 11 :after background size not working

Tags: css, internet-explorer-11

I added a background-image inside the pseudo :after

```
::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: -2.5rem;
  bottom: -1.5rem;

  height: 9.5rem;
  width: 9.5rem;
  background-image: url('../img/icons/icon_logo.svg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  // background-size: 100% auto;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

But the image is way bigger than the actual size of the box.

Any idea how to solve this?

(Working fine in webkit browsers)

**!!!Additional Information:**

I tried other svg and it works great.

Works:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 64 64" width="64" height="64">
  <path fill="#FF6C00" d="M0 0h64v64H0z"/>
  <path fill="#FFF" d="M33 0C22 0 13 9 ..."/>
</svg>
```

Does not work:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 64 64" width="64" height="64">
  <path fill="#FFF" d="M0 0h64v64H0z"/>
  <defs>
       <path id="a" d="M0 0h64v64H0z"/>
  </defs>
  <clipPath id="b">
       <use xlink:href="#a" overflow="visible"/>
  </clipPath>
  <path fill="#277052" d="M43.7 51.8s-...."/>
  <defs>
       <path id="c" d="M0 0h64v64H0z"/>
  </defs>
  <clipPath id="d">
       <use xlink:href="#c" overflow="visible"/>
  </clipPath>
  <path fill="#EE7203" d="M40.7 28.7c0 4.8-3..." clip-path="url(#d)"/>
  <path fill="#1D1D1B" d="M43 10.9c.2.1.4 0..." clip-path="url(#d)"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: can you provide fiddle for this?

Comment: What value do you have for `html -> font-size` ?

Comment: @MinalChauhan no fiddle yet

Comment: @Vucko font-size: I tried between 1px and 18px

Comment: please read my additional information

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IE11 using svg as background-image fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34225933/ie11-using-svg-as-background-image-fails)

Answer (score 2):

Read this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34270819/916937)

> Adobe Illustrator give me four options to declaring style sheet properties when saving graphics as an SVG file
>
> - Presentation Attributes
> - Style Attributes
> - Style Attributes (Entity Reference)
> - Style Elements
>
> No problem using the first three ways to styling properties, but embedding style sheets into SVG content inside a  element cause the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding in **display:block** to the css.

Comment: Try background-size: cover; too

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues rendering CSS in IE.
My solution:

- Make sure you have a `<!DOCTYPE>` declaration before your html
- Add the meta tag `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" >` (this makes sure that your code always renders the cutting edge or most updated version of internet explorer; else, it can render from older versions and things get really messy.)

I hope that helps.