# SVG path as div background

Tags: html, css, svg

I have an SVG path (as below) that I want to use as a background in a div, does anyone know how to do this, I've searched the web but cant find any simple examples?

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="4442" height="720" viewBox="0 0 4442 720">
  <path d="M36,297.64c317.62,0,428,134.58,696,136.74S1160,364,1436,389s431.72-102.09,618-91.36,505.93,73.37,715,72.29,339,72,674,64.45,712.27,157.83,920,174l46,111.14H36Z" transform="translate(0 0)" style="fill-opacity:0.029999999329447746"></path>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Simply use it as `background-image` then adjust the needed values:

```css
div.back {
  width:600px;
  height:120px;
  background-image:url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="500" height="100" viewBox="0 0 4442 720"><path d="M36,297.64c317.62,0,428,134.58,696,136.74S1160,364,1436,389s431.72-102.09,618-91.36,505.93,73.37,715,72.29,339,72,674,64.45,712.27,157.83,920,174l46,111.14H36Z" ></path></svg>');
  background-size:cover;
  background-color:pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="back"></div>
```

Comment: Great answer , never taught you can pass xml throw that  , Bahi :)

Comment: It's really working...That's Awesome

Answer (score 0):

you can't define an inline svg as background. You have 2 solutions here :

1 - store the svg as a separate file, and set it to `background-image: url('path/to/your/svg/file.svg');`

2 - If you really need to have it inline in your HTML for any reason, create another div, ste it to position absolute to make it fit ur main div. Then playing with `z-index` will lead you to the result you want

Comment: Good answer, though it does not really get clear how to style the second `div` container to show the scalar content.

Comment: As a note: You can also – with some [restrictions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34225933/1456376) in IE11 – use a (optionally base64 encoded) SVG in CSS directly as a background image.