# SVG-Path as background-image of an HTML-Element

Tags: html, css, svg

basically my question is the same as this one: [SVG path as div dackground](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49218238/svg-path-as-div-dackground/49218308#49218308)

I tried the solution given there, and it works in general.
My problem: I need to change the color of the line made with the SVG.
It is rendered in black and when I add the "fill"-Attribute to the path, nothing is rendered at all.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfwFK.png) is my rendered background image in the dev-tools

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please paste the code instead of screenshots.make it easier for people to help you...

Answer (score -1):

Background img isn't a part of the DOM and you can't manipulate it.  Possibility would be to use it regularly, embed it in a page in a normal way, but position it absolutely, make it full width & height of a page and then use z-index css property to put it behind all the other DOM elements on a page.

Answer (score -1):

Only you need to do is to add fill and fill-opacity property in style attribute like this

<path style="fill:red;fill-opacity:1;" ...>

```css
div.back {
  width:600px;
  height:120px;
  background-image:url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="500" height="100" viewBox="0 0 4442 720"><path style="fill:red;fill-opacity:1;" d="M36,297.64c317.62,0,428,134.58,696,136.74S1160,364,1436,389s431.72-102.09,618-91.36,505.93,73.37,715,72.29,339,72,674,64.45,712.27,157.83,920,174l46,111.14H36Z" ></path></svg>');
  background-size:cover;
  background-color:pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="back"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, it's really wired.
I have found a solution, you can write ***<path fill="blue"*** (with the name of the color similar to the result you want) and it works. But if you write ***#00F*** or ***"#00F"*** instead of ***"blue"*** it doesn't work!!! The reason is unknown, so I suggest you to use the name of a color similar to the hexadecimal rgb you want. 
Anyway, for the background-color if you write for example ***background-color:#7d212b;*** rather than ***background-color:pink;*** it works!

Comment: My question was flagged as duplicate and the following was linked in the message: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30733607/svg-data-image-not-working-on-firefox-or-chrome-72

And the solution given there actually works :) 
replace the '#' from the color code with '%23' and it works - the reason given is, that it is a url and therefore can't handle the '#' character ^^