# CSS - background svg not showing in IE

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a simple svg of a magnifying that I'm using as a background image in an input box.

It works in Chrome but nothing appears in the IE 10, 11 or edge browser.

Why doesn't it appear in IE browsers.

```css
.search{
  border-radius: 4px; 
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  max-width: 400px;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 30px;
  background: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' version='1' viewBox='0 0 22 22' %3E%3Cpath d='M14.92 14.07l6.04 6.04c.23.24.23.62 0 .86-.24.23-.62.23-.85 0l-6.03-6.04C12.57 16.22 10.63 17 8.5 17 3.8 17 0 13.2 0 8.5S3.8 0 8.5 0 17 3.8 17 8.5c0 2.13-.78 4.08-2.08 5.57zM8.5 16c4.14 0 7.5-3.36 7.5-7.5C16 4.36 12.64 1 8.5 1 4.36 1 1 4.36 1 8.5 1 12.64 4.36 16 8.5 16z' fill='#6f6f6f' fill-rule='nonzero'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: 8px center;
      background-size: 1.675em;
}
```

```html
<form action="">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search" class="search"> 
</form>
```

Comment: which IE version? update your question with this information, ty.

Comment: this will help you https://caniuse.com/#feat=svg

Comment: Except it doesn't help him as it is supported across the board.

Comment: are you sure your `svg` is valid?

Comment: I think it's valid, where would I check?

Comment: Check this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34270819/916937) . This might helps you.

Comment: Post your svg here, because the problem might come from it

Comment: The svg can be seen here - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YvzNWE

Comment: probably duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32870788/css-using-raw-svg-in-the-url-parameter-of-a-background-image-in-ie

Comment: I'm not familiar with this `svg+xml,%3 .... ` I meat the original `SVG` code? not the magnified one. and my question why don't you add the name like `url("../image.svg")`?

Answer (score 0):

add this to header

```
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
```

Comment: I have this in the actual page but I'm still not seeing the svg in IE