# How to draw RGB color picker gradients using SVG Graphics

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, colors

I want to draw RGB color models using SVG graphics that can be used in the color palette.

Image of the gradient can be viewed  [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TpNch.png)

1. I have tried to draw the gradient using SVG, but the result is not as expected.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width=256 height=256 >
  <defs>
     <linearGradient id='magenta' x1=0% y1=0% x2=100% y2=100%>
        <stop offset= 0% stop-color=#FF00FF stop-opacity=1></stop>
        <stop offset= 100% stop-color=#FFFFFF stop-opacity=0></stop>
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id='blue' x1=100% y1=0% x2=0% y2=100%>
        <stop offset= 0% stop-color=#0000FF stop-opacity=1></stop>
        <stop offset= 100% stop-color=#FFFFFF stop-opacity=0></stop>
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id='red' x1=0% y1=100% x2=100% y2=0%>
        <stop offset= 0% stop-color=#FF0000 stop-opacity=1></stop>
        <stop offset= 100% stop-color=#FFFFFF stop-opacity=0></stop>
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id='black' x1=100% y1=100% x2=0% y2=0%>
        <stop offset= 0% stop-color=#000000 stop-opacity=1></stop>
        <stop offset= 100% stop-color=#FFFFFF stop-opacity=0></stop>
    </linearGradient>
</defs>
<rect x=0 y=0 width=100% height=100% fill="url(#magenta)"></rect>
<rect x=0 y=0 width=100% height=100% fill="url(#blue)"></rect>
<rect x=0 y=0 width=100% height=100% fill="url(#red)"></rect>
<rect x=0 y=0 width=100% height=100% fill="url(#black)"></rect>
</svg>
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18452885/building-a-4-corners-colors-css3-gradient) describes how it can be done using CSS. I would like to know how to draw this gradient using SVG Graphics.

Comment: Just give a try http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Building a 4 corners-colors CSS3 gradient](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18452885/building-a-4-corners-colors-css3-gradient)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how you do it with SVG.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="256" height="256">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="magred" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%">
        <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#FF00FF"></stop>
        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#FF0000"></stop>
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id="magblue" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%">
        <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#FF00FF"></stop>
        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#0000FF"></stop>
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id="magredmaskgrad" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%">
        <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#FFFFFF"></stop>
        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#000000"></stop>
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id="magbluemaskgrad" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%">
        <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#FFFFFF"></stop>
        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#000000"></stop>
    </linearGradient>
    <mask id="magredmask">
        <rect x=0 y=0 width=100% height=100% fill="url(#magredmaskgrad)"/>
    </mask>
    <mask id="magbluemask">
        <rect x=0 y=0 width=100% height=100% fill="url(#magbluemaskgrad)"/>
    </mask>
</defs>
<rect x=0 y=0 width=100% height=100% fill="black"/>
<rect x=0 y=0 width=100% height=100% fill="url(#magred)"
      mask="url(#magredmask)"/>
<rect x=0 y=0 width=100% height=100% fill="url(#magblue)"
      mask="url(#magbluemask)"/>
</svg>
```

**How it works**

We combine two main gradients. Each has a graduated transparency mask running perpendicular to the colour gradient.

First there is a magenta to red gradient running from top to bottom. Its transparency runs from opaque on the left to transparent on the right.

On top of that is a magenta to blue gradient running from left to right.  Its transparency runs from opaque at the top to transparent on the bottom.

To provide the black at the bottom right, we insert a black square behind them both.

Answer (score 0):

Paul's answer put me on the right track for what I wanted to do - I wanted to make a four color gradient in Saturation / Lightness for a HSL space picker. Rather than masking and blending two opposite gradients, I used two same-oriented gradients and two transverse, flipped alpha masks (to make a blend function from the "left" gradient to the "right" gradient.)

I'm also including a mid point stop at L=0.5 to make sure I get some color in there.

Two other tweaks I had to make (Chrome; other browsers not yet tested) - the mask dimensions as percentages did not work for me but using `<rect x="0" y="0" width="1" height="1" fill="url(#maskGradient)"/>`

I also needed to add `maskContentUnits="objectBoundingBox"` to the masks - at least for my use case, and how I wanted it positioned.