# CSS linear gradient background changes over time

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to create a div with a gradient background (2 colors from top to bottom) that changes colors over time.

**For example**: the div has a red (top) and blue (bottom) linear gradient background and I want it to gradually turn yellow (top) and purple (bottom) after ten minutes.

**Important**: the background must not change suddenly when 10 minutes have elapsed but must change little by little for the entire duration of 10 minutes.

**My needs**: what I should do is change the background to recreate the colors of the sky in the most realistic way possible.  So having available the times of sunset, sunrise, day, and night and their respective durations, I wanted to change the color of the background recreating the sky in those moments of the day.  The result would be animations of the same duration of day, night, sunset and sunrise that change the background color with gradients.
Dynamically changing the duration of the animation and checking what time of day I am in order to start the correct animation of the background colors I am able to do it but I don't know how to animate the linear gradient over time.

How can I do that?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far? One strategy I can think of is gradually increasing/decreasing the RGB values every 1 second or so from the initial colour to the final one.

Comment: I didn't try anything because I have no idea how this can be done. I will probably try to do something this weekend but I really don't have any ideas of how to do that. This is why I asked for help there.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you wanted:

```js
var intervalID;
var seconds=20;//Here u set time
var updateTimeMs = 10;
var noSteps=seconds*1000/updateTimeMs;

intervalID = setInterval(myTimer, updateTimeMs);
var counter=0;

function myTimer() {
  counter++;
  if (counter == noSteps)
     clearInterval(intervalID);
    
    var prcStep = Math.trunc(counter/noSteps*100);        
    var newValDown =  Math.trunc(255-(255/100)*prcStep);
    var newValUp =  Math.trunc((255/100)*prcStep);
        
    
  document.getElementById("myDiv").style.backgroundColor = `rgba(255,${newValUp},0,1)`;
  document.getElementById("myDiv").style.backgroundImage =`linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.01) 1%,rgba(${newValUp},0,255,1) 100%)`;
  }
```

```css
.grad {
  background-color : rgba(255,0,0,1);
  background-image:linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.01) 1%,rgba(0,0,255,1) 100%);
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv" class="grad" style="width:600px;height:200px;border:solid 1px black">

</div>
```

Comment: This is a great solution but unfortunately I don't think it's adaptable to my case or at least I think there are better solutions.  I've updated my problem description to be as clear as possible.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is create a gradient containing all of your colors red top & blue bottom on the left & yellow top & purple bottom, and you would animate that by moving it around slowly. In that case i don't think `background: linear-gradient` does animate so maybe refer to [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18452885/building-a-4-corners-colors-css3-gradient) method

```
.grad {
    background-color : rgba(255,0,0,1);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.01) 1%, rgba(0,0,255,1) 100%);
    animation: gradient 3600s ease linear;
}
@keyframes gradient {
    0% {
        background-position: left;
    }
    100% {
        background-position: right;
    }
```